# jQuery - horizontal accordion onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write a very simple horizontal accordion sort of thing.

I have three 'banner' divs and three 'area' divs so when I click the banner, the corresponding area should, ideally, animate to allow the width to go to auto and the height to go from min-height to auto if required.

The code I have so far is working fine on my site but not on jfiddle, which makes me believe a silly mistake in the jfiddle entering:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8tvetr7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#second_line_accordian_banner_one").click(function(){
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast");
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast");
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").animate({width:"300px"}, "slow", swing);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#second_line_accordian_banner_two").click(function(){
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast");
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast");
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").animate({width:"300px"}, 2000, swing);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#second_line_accordian_banner_three").click(function(){
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast");
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast");
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").animate({width:"300px"}, 1000, swing);
  });
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Forgot to mention, on my site it does technically slide to 300px but it is very, very clunky.

Comment: check this http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-target/accordionhorz.html#acc1, it is css based one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8tvetr7/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#second_line_accordian_banner_one").click(function(){
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast"),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast"),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").css( {'display':'none'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").css( {'display':'none'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").css( {'display':'block'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").animate({width:"300px"}, "slow");
  }),

  $("#second_line_accordian_banner_two").click(function(){
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast"),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast"),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").css({ 'display':'none'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").css( {'display':'none'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").css( {'display':'block'}),
        $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").animate({ width:"300px"},600);
  }),

  $("#second_line_accordian_banner_three").click(function(){
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast"),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").animate({width:"0px"}, "fast"),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_one").css( {'display':'none'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_two").css( {'display':'none'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").css( {'display':'block'}),
    $("#second_line_accordian_area_three").animate({ width:"300px"},600);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate jQuery in the left menu of JSFiddle